# Android: proguard is not obfuscating the source

Tags: android, proguard

I have enabled proguard in project.properties:

proguard.config=proguard.cfg

My proguard.cfg does not disable obfuscation. But nothing is obfuscated.

I run the project build with

ant release.

Any bells ringing?

---

> -optimizationpasses 5
>   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -dontpreverify
>   -verbose
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
>   -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>       native ; }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {    public void *(android.view.View); }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>       public static **[] values();
>       public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }

---

Comment: How do you check that nothing is obfuscated? Can you post here your proguard.cfg? Do you see in the ant output that proguard is processing your files?

Comment: Edited the question with proguard.cfg. I just throw an exception in the source and watch the stacktrace. Kind of stupid, but still works. And I notice that classes that should be obfuscated are not. Also, when building, I see nothing when the build goes through "obfuscating" phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was way more trivial than what I thought: we had (in our manifest.xml file) enabled the

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Doh.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your project is configured for your Android SDK:

```
android update project -p MyProjectDirectory
```

As of Android SDK r20, the ProGuard configuration file is split into several parts, which are specified in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

The short project-specific configuration is defined in `proguard-project.txt` (no longer in proguard.cfg, like it was in older versions of the SDK). The SDK documentation may not be entirely up to date in this respect.

When you run `ant release`, you should see some logging output from ProGuard.

Answer (score 1):

@Thanks Danail, Today i just overcome from this problem .Just elaborating

**`android:debuggable`**
Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode — *`"true"`* if it can be, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".

For more details you can visit

> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDebugging/article.html